# material-ui form label positions

Tags: css, reactjs, forms, material-ui, formik-material-ui

Making a form with `Material-ui` + `react`. Is there a way to layout the labels to the side of input fields? It's much more readable.

so like this:

```
name   [input]
title  [input]
```

rather than

```
name  
[input]
title 
[input]
```

I can only find fields that have the label and input area mashed together in one.
I could build my own component or a grid, but it seems this is an obvious layout that should exist.

docs page
https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/

[image]

[image]

Comment: use this [link](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#input-adornments)

Comment: if you look above I added a screenshot from that page already... >.<

Comment: not image above . this link contain `Kg` .That you can replace the input name .

Comment: all the forms on that link are vertically stacked, same as my bad examples above.
it seems form-control-label maybe the way.
https://material-ui.com/api/form-control-label/
demo is better here
https://material-ui.com/components/checkboxes/

but not sure now how to pass those complex components into react-hook-form.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue, the only way I've found to solve the problem was by using "[sx](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/)" which allows you to override the CSS.

```
<InputLabel htmlFor="login" sx={{display: 'inline'}}>Login :</InputLabel>
<Input  id="login" type="text" value={login} onInput={ e=>setLogin(e.target.value)} />
```